# Branchless (MIPS) assembly code for median of 3

Tags: integer, tips, sorting, atomic-code-golf, assembly

I was trying to write a short MIPS32 code for computing the median of three registers.

The rules:

- Assume that some values are pre-loaded into `$t0`, `$t1`, `$t2`.
- The median of the three values should be placed in `$t0`.
- No branches are allowed, but otherwise any instruction is okay.
- You may arbitrarily modify the values of all registers.

I was able to optimize it down to 15 instructions. Can you do better?

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I added the [tag:code-golf] tag, but other than that this challenge looks good. (You might still want to check out the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for future challenges, it can be pretty useful sometimes)

Comment: @RedwolfProgrammed - thanks!

Comment: I've retagged this as [tag:atomic-code-golf] since the count seems to be the number of instructions, although this could be made more clear in the body of the challenge.

Comment: May I modify some specific addresses in memory? May I use jump instructions `j/jal/jr`? May I modify the code during execution?

Comment: @Bubbler - *anything* is allowed except branches.

Comment: @GrainGhost I believe MIPS instructions are always 4 bytes so code golf would work as well

Answer (score 8):

## 7 instructions

```
slt $t3, $t0, $t1
slt $t4, $t2, $t1
slt $t5, $t2, $t0
```

Compare all three pairs of values.

```
xor $t3, $t3, $t4
movn $t0, $t1, $t3
```

`$t1` is the median if it is greater than exactly one of the other values.

```
xor $t5, $t5, $t4
movn $t0, $t2, $t5
```

`$t2` is the median if it is less than exactly one of the other values.

(Otherwise, `$t0` is already the median.)

Comment: Very nice. I followed the same logic, but my implementation required more than twice the number of instructions :).

Answer (score 5):

## 8 instructions

```
slt $t4, $t2, $t1
movn $t3, $t1, $t4
movn $t1, $t2, $t4
movn $t2, $t3, $t4
```

Rearrange `$t1` and `$t2` so that `$t1` ≤ `$t2`.

```
slt $t3, $t2, $t0
slt $t4, $t0, $t1
movn $t0, $t2, $t3
movn $t0, $t1, $t4
```

If `$t0` falls between `$t1` and `$t2`, it is already the median. If it's outside that range, the one it lies beyond is the median.